# Corda OS 4.4 Migrating Data between Cordapp deployments

Tags: corda

I have a project where I need to deploy my corda nodes multiple times going from development to pre-production to production environments. Each of these environments has there own data which are stored on the node but of course this data must be manually re-entered by an admin. Delivery is around the corner and we are now trying to figure out how to essentially create some way of allowing us to do CD type situation. That is to say we would like to provide some updates to the cordapps but on a "live" situation where data is in use.

I was wondering is there anyway to do a data migration to facilitate these updates? There would unlikely be corda version updates in between these deployments but, there could be schema and state changes etc.

There is probably a situation I am missing but even a solution such as dumping out the database and then running a schema script or something and then importing into database is viable.

We are running this on Corda OS 4.4, with the H2 database.

Edit: if the answer could be given in the context of how one might go about in the case of a non-backwards compatible schema change for instance deletion of data, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you would not be using  H2 on pre-prod or Prod env.Let us say you are using postgres , you will bring down your node to do schema update and other DB related changes or corda upgrade . Data can be retained on the nodes on every depoyment. The above question seems very broad .

Comment: Hi Manish, Thanks for your comment. I suppose the specific questions is are there any "Gotchas" or nuances to retaining data during deployment specifically pertaining to building/rebuilding nodes? Let's say that I use postgres, if I bring down the node for redployment I am going to take down the old node and then I might do some schema update (liquibase script from my readings) and then bring up the new node with the new build (let's say with a schema change or some such) by replacing any jar files (node executables) and Cordapp files. in this scenario, I should expect my data to be retained?

Comment: If you are bringing up the same node after table schema changes ,your node will have the old data retained . check this link it might help [corda resetting node](
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/performance-testing/practical-considerations.html#postgresoracle)

Comment: So I suppose really this falls more under db maintenance than Corda specific applications. The fact that schema is generic means that SQL querying and essentially lining db and schema up are enough to ensure any migrations will hold going from development to production etc. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manish has already broken this down in the comments, I'd say to just take a look at what the database looks like, and make sure to understand schema migrations.

Also, be aware that you have a param you should add to your cordapps for schema migrations

```py
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }

        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
        runSchemaMigration = true

        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Features/postgres-cordapp/build.gradle#L99-L109

links on schema migrations:

- https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/node-database-migration-logging.html
- https://www.corda.net/blog/upgrade-to-corda-os-46the-database-migration/

links on database tables:

- https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/node/operating/node-database-tables.html#database-tables

Comment: Thanks David for your response. I found in my particular situation https://www.corda.net/blog/upgrade-to-corda-os-46the-database-migration/ to be particularly helpful.
In our case we are running OS 4.4 which has limited access to any corda based functionality for run schema so I think it's basically on an admin to generate and run any upgrade scripts themselves. Still, Thanks.